# How to write solr query in java for multiple sub-queries?

Tags: java, solr

Could someone help in converting the following solr query into java?

```
http://<server>/solr/<core>/select?debugQuery=on&indent=on&q=(_query_:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='manu^2.0' v=$q1}") 
AND (_query_:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='category^2.0' v=$q1}")&q1=galaxy&wt=csv
```

I need to know how I can set the multiple sub-queries into query.

Edit 2: In order to get accurate response, I queried 3 times until response is received.

```
query.setQuery("manu:"+prefix+" AND category:"+prefix);
        QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
        if (response.getResults().getNumFound() == 0) {
            query.setQuery("manu:"+prefix+" OR category:"+prefix);
            response = server.query(query);
            if (response.getResults().getNumFound() == 0) {
                query.setQuery("text:"+prefix);
                response = server.query(query);
            }    
        }
```

But it is causing too much delay? Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made little modifications in your query to make it more simpler

> q=(category:$q1^2.0 AND manu:$q1^2.0)&defType=edismax&q1=galaxy&wt=csv&fl=manu,category

Create Solrclient object

> String urlString = "http://server:port/solr/core";
>
> SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

Create SolrQuery object and on that object execute the query method like this and also set various parameters

> query.set("q", "category:galaxy AND manu:galaxy");
>
> query.set("qt", "/search");
>
> query.set("mm", "100%");
>
> query.setQueryType("edismax");
>
> query.set("qf", "category^2.0 manu^2.0");
>
> QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(query);

you will get the list of SolrDocumentList, on which you could iterate and got the results back.

> SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();

Please refer to [SolrJ Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ) as per the solr version you are using.

Comment: Good to know ;)

Comment: I added one more edit in question @Aman Tandon Could you please help?

Comment: Did you mean that subquery ?

Comment: @ShubhraSinha I hope this will help you, &q=((manu:galaxy AND category:galaxy) OR (business:galaxy OR category:galaxy) OR text:galaxy). i replied late sry for that.